# Recursively rename files using find and sed

Tags: bash, scripting, find, rename, sed

I want to go through a bunch of directories and rename all files that end in _test.rb to end in _spec.rb instead. It's something I've never quite figured out how to do with bash so this time I thought I'd put some effort in to get it nailed. I've so far come up short though, my best effort is:

```
find spec -name "*_test.rb" -exec echo mv {} `echo {} | sed s/test/spec/` \;
```

*NB: there's an extra echo after exec so that the command is printed instead of run while I'm testing it.*

When I run it the output for each matched filename is:

```
mv original original
```

i.e. the substitution by sed has been lost. What's the trick?

Comment: I can tell you what's wrong, but I'm not sure how to tell you to fix it: bash is immediately executing `echo {} | sed s/test/spec/`, which produces {}, then bash executes the find command.  Have you checked to see whether your distribution has a good `rename` program?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have `rename` (it's a really short Perl script) or your rename is the more simplistic util-linux version or you simply want to know how to make your command work: you just need to send it to the shell for execution:

```
find spec -name "*_test.rb" -exec sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed s/test.rb\$/spec.rb/)"' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Too complicated. If you have the `rename` command available, you could try the following:

```
find . -name "*_test.rb" -print0 | xargs -0 rename "s/_test/_spec/"
```

This finds the relevant files, sends them to xargs which in turn uses the rename tool (which renames files according to the given perl regex).

Comment: +1 for `-print0`. Also, I'd make the regexp pattern as axplicit as possible: `"s/_test.rb$/_spec.rb/"` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: note that only works if you happen to have the perl script version of rename, not the standard rename that comes with util-linux.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of util-linux's rename:

```
   rename '_with_long_name' '' file_with_long_name.*

will remove the substring in the filenames.
```

So this command works if you do not have the Perl version of rename:

```
find . -name "*_test.rb" -print0 | xargs -0 rename "_test..rb" "_spec/rb"
```